# How to keep current user cross all components in angular2/4

Tags: angular

I need this `current_user` across the app in different components. Is this a service job?

How do I do this? It doesn't feel right to use `Service` this way..

```
import { Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http } from '@angular/http';
import { User } from './user';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable()
export class UserService implements OnInit {

  private host = 'http://localhost:3000';
  private userUrl = 'api/user';

  currentUser: User;

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getUser().then( user => this.currentUser = user);
  }

  getUser() : Promise<User> {
    const url = `${this.host}/${this.userUrl}`;
    return this.http.get(url)
      .toPromise()
      .then(res => res.json().data as User)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
    console.error('An error occurred', error);
    return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
  }

}
```

In other component:

```
  currentUser: User;

  constructor(private userService: UserService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.currentUser = this.userService.currentUser;
    console.log(this.currentUser);
  }
```

Comment: This seems like exactly where you'd want to use a service. Your code is fine.

Comment: Services are made for this. Well done mate! ;)

Comment: First of all `ngOnInit` is component life cycle hook, not intended for service.

Comment: I think it is better to let `getUser` work as a singleton, so when you call it, if `User user` is null, ask for it . That way you will not run into situation where you call `currentUser` from a component, and it returns null.

Comment: Actually, my code is wrong. Given its' a singleton, the OnInit seems just not applying here. So I have to call "this.userService.getUser()" within the component where I want to get the currentUser. At least, this works. But it's bit troublesome without accessing a property of the singleton.

Comment: Knowing nothing of the setup. Is there no component, like a login page or something that will first get the user and then you can proceed to other pages?

Comment: I have a "nav" component which displays the current user name and it uses this service. And I have other component which need to access current user as well. Currently this is just one page(route). Based on what I have said, it seems that this service cannot hold the user as a value cross all components, let alone routes I guess. Which is just not feeling very right as being a singleton to me..

Comment: Well it should be able to persist the user, just wondering about the flow of the app, meaning does components get rendered before data has been set etc. Best would be if you could create a plunker that showcases the issue :)